# When i use if else condition in query based on condition, how can i get that value on view in PHP CODEIGNITER

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am confuse with this problem in mysql, I have two table, "A" and "B"

```
TableA:
S.No    contact1 contact2  status
 1        Blbh    eeee       1

TAbleB:
S.No     Phone1   phone2
 1        ddd     ssss
```

From this table i am going to get value, from TableA ia m going to check

```
if (status == 1)
{
  run tableA;
}
else
{
  run table b;
}
```

I am gone a return result of this query. In view, how to get value with respected column name. I have no idea of this, help me to get value in view.

```
public function contDetails($id){
        $check = $this->db->query("SELECT contact_status FROM account WHERE id = '$id' ");
        $str = $check->row();
        $chk = $str->contact_status;

        if($chk == 1){
            $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM account WHERE id = '$id'");
        }else{
            $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM contact_details WHERE user_id = '$id'");
        }

        $run = $query->num_rows();

        print_r($run);

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use in your model

```
$query = $this->db->get(); //---  run the query  ---//
return $query->result() //---  to get result in array of object  ---//
```

and then in your view use foreach loop

```
foreach($results as $result){
 echo $result->columnName;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, suppose, if TableB runs means i have different colunName, on that situation how can i differentiate table (column name), for sample i will upload my code see it friend.

Comment: for this situation you can set a flag, if you are getting value from table1 then set $flag = 'table1' otherwise $flag = 'table2' and then return this flag to your view as well and then in view check the value of flag in if-else condition as you have done in controller.. may be this can help

Comment: Ya thank you mansoor, I set a flag in two queries  seprated in veiw depend up on set flag. I got answer thank you

Answer (score 0):

have you already written the query in mysql? If yes and if you are concerned about whether the column name to use exist or not you can use isset...

Answer (score 0):

in your view you can use like the following:

```
     <?php

      foreach($results as $result)
      {
          echo (isset($result['col1']))?$result['col1']:$result['col1_2'];
      }


     ?>
```

And don't forget to use result_array() instsead of result in the controller